# How to add explicit NTFS permissions without disabling inheritance on child folders

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have a scenario with lot of child folders and some of them needs to have explicit NTFS permissions without disabling inherited NTFS permissions. Looks something like below

root (contains NTFS group-root)
  child1 - Needs explicit permissions(contains group-root, needs to add group-child1)
  child2 - Doesn't need a change(contains group-root)
  child3 - Needs explicit permissions(contains group-root, needs to add group-child3)
  child4 - Needs explicit permissions(contains group-root, needs to add group-child4)
  child5 - Needs explicit permissions(contains group-root, needs to add group-child5)
  child6 - Doesn't need a change(contains group-root)
  child7 - Doesn't need a change(contains group-root)

Is there a way to have only group-childX on child folders that needs explicit permissions without disabling inheritance

Note: The users present in group-root may also be in group-child1, group-child3, group-child4 and group-child5. The reason to have this is because the child folders that needs explicit permissions (without disabling inheritance) is for a particular domain user holding sensitive data that needs to be shared with only group-childX NTFS group. I dont want to remove inherit permissions because that would make folder administration too complicated. I tried adding deny permissions for group-root on the child folders child1, child3, child4, child5 and adding group-childX but it denied access for users in both the groups.

Comment: Of course this is possible. Add an ACE for the relevant groups to the ACL of the relevant folder. So, add the permissions for group to the child folder. You can have both inherited and explicit (direct) permissions defined on a folder.

Comment: Thank you Joeqwerty. The purpose is i have to deny permissions for users and groups on child folders and i tried applying deny write ACE on relevant ACL's but somehow it denied the read permissions as well.

Answer (score 1):

To remove groups or users ACE without disabling inheritance, use `CACLS *folder* /E /R *group/user*`. I know that CACLS is deprecated but I have not found any equivalent when using `iCacls` or `SETACL`.